# how to open an aspx.cs file?

Tags: asp.net

i have some files with extension aspx.cs.
i tried opening them with visual studio c# 2008.
but all that opens is the code page, and not any design page.

what should i do?
i have to work on that project.
how to open those files, in which program/software?

please help.

Comment: instead of posting the same comment repeatedly, you should read the answers people are giving you.  You have the right files.  What do you see when you open the `.aspx` file?  Do you have a project file?

Comment: oops sorry!! well, the .aspx file gets opened in the visual studio, but despite my all efforts, m not able to see the "design" option anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Open the project .csproj or .sln file if there is one

Comment: If you don't have a .csproj, this is a website not a web-project, there's a different option in the file menu.

Comment: i have both the aspx and aspx.cs files. both get opened in visual studio c# 2008 express version, but none shows the design. am i using the wrong visual studio version or what??

Answer (score 2):

The design files end with an extension aspx. The aspx.cs files are the code behind files and do not contain any design elements. Open the .aspx files in visual studio and you will have the proper design page.

Comment: i have both the aspx and aspx.cs files. both get opened in visual studio c# 2008 express version, but none shows the design. am i using the wrong visual studio version or what??

Comment: There is a design view and a source view even for aspx files in visual studio. Open the aspx file and at the bottom, you will see three options "design", "split" and "source". Click on "design". Or in the solution explorer, right click on the aspx file and click on "view designer"

Comment: @mallika Can you upload a screenshot somewhere and post a link of your screen with the aspx file opened in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

The aspx.cs files only contain the code living behind the aspx files (that's why they are called code-behind files). If you want to be able to see the design you have to open an aspx file with the same name.

For example, if you have customers.aspx.cs, it contains the code-behind of a page called customers.aspx.

If you only have aspx.cs but not aspx, then you have a problem, as probably you lost files of the project.

Comment: i have both the aspx and aspx.cs files. both get opened in visual studio c# 2008 express version, but none shows the design. am i using the wrong visual studio version or what??

Answer (score 0):

Hai!!
.cs files are code files .aspx files are desidn files where you can switch from asp tages to asp design view but .cs files are c# code file that has no design

Happy Codding
Jay

Answer (score -1):

For the Design File in .net Extension is only `.aspx`, Please open `.aspx` files instead of `.aspx.cs` Files